# How to Get rid of JSON decoding of remote response failed (error code 4)?

Tags: php, selenium, phpstorm

and thanks very much for reading this :)

I've had a problem with the installation of selenium on my computer for quite some time now , and my internship manager is starting to get steamed :'(

Have a wonderful day , thanks for reading this !

Basically , i've installed Php version 7.0 and 5.6 (i'll get back to that in a bit)
I've also installed Xdebug, i had no problem with that.
When i try to connect to localhost:444 it says that the connection would not be allowed.
I have tried opening the port 4444 , disabling the firewall however it doesnt change a thing :'(
I've run out of options :'(

<

```
?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

$host = 'http://localhost'; // this is the default
$USE_FIREFOX = true; // if false, will use chrome.

if ($USE_FIREFOX)
{
    $driver = Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create(
        $host,
        Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::firefox()
    );
}
else
{
    $driver = Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create(
        $host,
        Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::chrome()
    );
}

$driver->get("http://www.google.com");

# enter text into the search field
$driver->findElement(Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy::id('lst-ib'))->click();
sleep(1);
$driver->findElement(Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy::id('lst-ib'))->sendKeys('programster selenium');
sleep(1);

# Click the search button
$driver->findElement(Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy::name('btnK'))->click();
```

> /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/symfony-test/seleniumtest.php
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException: JSON decoding of remote response failed.

```
Error code: 4
The response: '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>'
 in /var/www/html/symfony-test/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:303
```

> Stack trace:
>       #0 /var/www/html/symfony-test/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php(144): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor->execute(Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCommand))
>       #1 /var/www/html/symfony-test/seleniumtest.php(12): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhos...', Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities))
>       #2 {main}
>         thrown in /var/www/html/symfony-test/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php on line 303

Comment: `404 Not Found` means the page you are trying to load does not exist

Comment: hi and thank you for replying.
The page i'm looking for is google. I must be doing something wrong because it definitely exists

Comment: Fixed the ISSUE , it turns out that you have to pay close attention to the Chromedriver version that you install with google chrome (version 76 for chrome , therefore chromedriver has to be 76 you'll find more info on the chromedriver download page.)
Thank you very much and have a wonderful day !